# Calculate Sum of Oracle Apex Tabular Form Field

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-apex, tabular-form

There is a `column` as `Price` in my oracle apex tabular form. I need to calculate `sum` of all fields under this column and assign it to hidden field in Master form for validation.
Actually there is a filed as `Total_Price` in master form. Value of this `Total_Price` field must be equals to sum of `Price` in detail form.
 but i don't  know how to calculate `sum` of `Price` `column` in my oracle apex tabular form. how could i do this?

Comment: At what point do you need to do this - as data is being entered, or once it has been entered and page is submitted?

Comment: @TonyAndrews at once it has been entered and click on Apply Changes Button. Before inserting to the database.

Comment: @TonyAndrews how could i do this when data is being entered ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to do these when the Apply Changes button has been pressed, you can do it in a page process.

You need to identify which Apex array holds the data from that tabular form column - e.g. apex_application.g_f01, apex_application.g_f02, ...  One way is to view the page source when running the page and look for the elements that make up the column.  If they have the attribute `name="f01"` then the array you need is apex_application.g_f01, and so on.

Then simply write this code in the page process (I have assumed the array required is g_f01):

```
declare
   l_tot number := 0;
begin
   for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count loop
      l_tot := l_tot + nvl(to_number(apex_application.g_f01(i)),0);
   end loop;
   :p123_hidden_total := l_tot;
end;
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer of me here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8488091/814048 too: a mapping is also in the html source by which you can determine the arrays. Careful with apex_item usage though (because you assign an id manually). As for the sum, could you not also do a ´select sum() into´ after the MRU process? Result'd be the same though :)